Exercise (E.1.3) of the book 'Lectures on von Neumann Algebras'
I am stuck in the following exercise (E.1.3) of the book 'Lectures on von Neumann Algebras'. The exercise is following:

(E.1.3) With the help of E.1.2, show that for any $w$-continuous linear form $\varphi$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, there exist two sequences $\{ \xi_n \},\{\eta_n\}\subset \mathcal{H}$ such that $\sum_k \|\xi_k\|^2< \infty, \sum_k \|\eta_k\|^2< \infty$ and
$$
\varphi = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \omega_{\xi_k, \eta_k}
$$

I have already solved E.1.2 and want to use this to solve this exercise. Here is what I have done so far:
Let $\varphi\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})_{*}$. Choose a sequence $(\varphi_n)_{n\ge 1} \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})_{\sim}$ s.t. $\|\varphi - \varphi_n\|\le \frac{1}{2^{n + 2}}$. Then we get
$$
\|\varphi_n - \varphi_{n-1}\|< \frac{1}{2^n}, (n \ge 2) \text{ and } \|\varphi_1\|\le \|\varphi\| + \frac{1}{2^3}
$$
Now if we define $\omega_1 := \varphi_1$ and $\omega_n := \varphi_n - \varphi_{n-1}, (n \ge 2)$, then $\omega_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})_{\sim}$ and $\varphi = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\omega_n$. Now by E.1.2 for all $n\ge 1$ there exists orthogonal sets $\{\xi_1^n, \dots, \xi_{k_n}^n\}, \{\eta_1^n, \dots, \eta_{k_n}^n\}\subset \mathcal{H}$ such that:
$$
\omega_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{k_n} \omega_{\xi_i^n, \eta_i^n} \text{ and } \|\omega_n\|= \sum_{i = 1}^{k_n} \|\xi_i^n\|\|\eta_i^n\|
$$
Therefore we got, $\varphi = \sum_{n =1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{k_n}\omega_{\xi_i^n, \eta_i^n}\right)$, which is an infinite sum of the forms $\omega_{\xi, \eta}$. But to complete the proof we need to verify:
$$
\sum_{n =1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{k_n}\|\xi_i^n\|^2\right)<\infty
$$
and similar for $\eta_i^n$.
How can I show this? Thanks.

As is, you cannot really verify that. Instead, replace $\xi_i^n$ by $\frac{\sqrt{|\xi_i^n||\eta_i^n|}}{|\xi_i^n|}\xi_i^n$ and similarly for $\eta_i^n$.

@DavidGao, Thanks
